# rvest - select only certain hrefs under class

Tags: html, r, rvest

**Objective**

Scrape a vector of file paths to retail store locations, while ignoring the hyperlinked telephone number. I am new to working with html elements.

**What I have tried**

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

store.paths <- read_html("https://www.walmart.com/store/directory/al/alabaster") %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="store-directory-container"]') %>% 
    html_nodes("a") %>% 
    html_attr('href')
```

which yields

```
[1] "/store/4756"      "tel:205-624-6229" "/store/423"       "tel:205-620-0360"
```

while my desire output is

```
[1] "/store/4756"  "/store/423"
```

I have tried replacing `store-directory-container` with `storeBanner` and the result is empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `a` tags you want also have the class `storeBanner` while the telephone links do not. It would be easy to grab them with

```
store.paths <- read_html("https://www.walmart.com/store/directory/al/alabaster") %>%
  html_elements("a.storeBanner") %>% 
  html_attr('href')
```

I also used the CSS selector syntax in this case because it's easier and use the recommend `html_elements` function because `html_nodes` is soft-deprecated. You can't just replace "store-directory-container" with "storeBanner" because the the "a" tag is below the "store-directory-container" but in the case of "storeBanner" it is that element, not a child of that element.

Comment: Good to know html_nodes is soft-deprecated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more xpath with storeBanner after tag

```
store.paths <- read_html("https://www.walmart.com/store/directory/al/alabaster") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="store-directory-container"]') %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="storeBanner"]') %>% 
  html_attr('href') 

store.paths

[1] "/store/4756" "/store/423"
```